# Making this function more "elegant" C++

Tags: c++, performance, recursion, processing-efficiency

Is there anyway to make this recursive function more elegant? I'd like to make the function so there is no repeated code.

```
int findMaximumValue(int list[], int first, int last)
{
    if (first == last)
        return list[first];
    else {
        if (list[first] > findMaximumValue(list, first + 1, last))
            return list[first];
        else
            return findMaximumValue(list, first + 1, last);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the function work as it should? Then if you want a code-review please post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Yes it does, and thanks, I'll post it over there instead.

Comment: No it doesn't, it"s got wrong complexity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is for finding solutions to coding problems.  For advice on improving working code, please use [codereview.se] instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *two* things that pop immediately into mind:

- The first is to avoid the `if ... then return else ...` paradigm, since the `return` makes the `else` superfluous.
- The second is to do the recusrsive call only *once* (since it's invariant).

Making those changes would give you something like:

```
int findMaximumValue(int list[], int first, int last) {
    // List has one item, return it.

    if (first == last)
        return list[first];

    // Get largest of all but first element in list.

    int maxOfAllButFirst = findMaximumValue(list, first + 1, last);

    // First is larger than all those others, return it.

    if (list[first] > maxOfAllButFirst)
        return list[first];

    // Otherwise it's largest from the others.

    return maxOfAllButFirst;
}
```

---

I should mention however that recursion is best done for algorithms where the solution space reduces quickly (such as a binary search where you discard half the remaining solution space on each recursive call).

Using recursion for something where the solution space reduces slowly (such as this, which is basically a linear search) is not the best idea. If it cannot do tail call optimisation, you're likely to run out of stack space fairly quickly.

In other words, the best way to make *this* algorithm more elegant is to turn it from a recursive one into an iterative one :-)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. The **else** is what I was trying to get rid of!

Comment: And yes this binary search vs linear search is what I am learning right now. It basically can search for target in 11 iterations instead of 1024 in linear. This is just a simple assignment for the comparasion between the way linear and binary is coded. The list size in my case is only 100 so it is not too bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use functions from the standard library, you can simplify the function to:

```
int findMaximumValue(int list[], int first, int last)
{
    if (first == last)
        return list[first];

    return std::max(list[first], findMaximumValue(list, first + 1, last));
}
```

If you are not allowed to use any of the functions from the standard libray, write your own `max` function and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can compute maximum from second to last element, save it to a variable and then use it:

```
int findMaximumValue(int list[], int first, int last)
{
    if (first == last)
        return list[first];
    else {
        int maxFromSecond = findMaximumValue(list, first + 1, last);
        if (list[first] > maxFromSecond)
            return list[first];
        else
            return maxFromSecond;
    }
}
```

Or, another way, you can use function `max(int, int)` to shorten your function:

```
int findMaximumValue(int list[], int first, int last)
{
    if (first == last)
        return list[first];
    else
        return max(list[first], findMaximumValue(list, first + 1, last));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is an alternative, calling with next=1, last=number of items of list and currMax as the first item of list

```
int findMaximumValue(int list[], int nextIndex, int last, int currMax)
{
    if (nextIndex == last)
        return currMax;

    int max = list[nextIndex] > currMax ? list[nextIndex] : currMax;
    return findMax(list, ++nextIndex, last, max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most elegant code ;)

```
int findMaximumValue(void* list, int nextIndex, int last, int sizeofelem)
{
    int result;
    __asm {  
          push eax
          push ecx  
          push esi
          push edi       
          mov eax, nextIndex
          mov ecx, eax
          mul sizeofelem      
          mov esi, list       
          add esi, eax
          mov edi, esi
next:                     
          cmp ecx, last
          je  stop
comp: 
          add esi, sizeofelem
          inc ecx
          mov eax, [edi]
          cmp eax, [esi]          
          jl setgrte
          jmp next                
setgrte:  
          mov edi, esi
          jmp next
stop: 
          mov eax, [edi]
          mov [result], eax
          pop edi
          pop esi           
          pop ecx                                 
          pop eax
    } 
    return result;
}
//.....
int res = findMaximumValue((void*)&arr, lov, hiv, sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about get rid of your function and just use this standard algorithm:

```
std::max_element(list, list + len);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/

or sort the list:

```
  int myints[] = {32,71,12,45,26,80,53,33};
  std::vector<int> myvector (myints, myints+8);               // 32 71 12 45 26 80 53 33

  std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), std::greater<>()); //sort descending

  return *(myvector.begin());
```